# Why do I keep getting the lifetime of the W boson as being $10^{-15}$ rather than $10^{-25}$?

Tags: particle-physics

I need to calculate the lifetime of the W boson given its decay width. From what I know the lifetime of a particle is calculated by dividing $\hbar$ with the decay width $\Gamma$. From my textbook $\Gamma=2.141 $ GeV, and $\hbar=6.852 \times10^{-15} $Gev$\cdot$s, doing the lifetime calculation with these values gives me:

$$\tau=\hbar/\Gamma\approx3.2\times10^{-15}s$$

I know the correct solution is $3.2\times10^{-25}s$, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get that number. What am I missing here?

Comment: Which unit has $\hbar=6.852 \times10^{-15}$? eVs, or GeVs, or something else?

Comment: @ThomasFritsch I apologize, the units are Gev$\cdot$s. I have edited my post.

Comment: Look at [Wikipedia:Planck constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant). They have $\hbar = 6.582 \cdot 10^{-16}$ eVs. (i.e. without G)

Comment: You seem to have done an incorrect conversion from $eV$ to $GeV$ as $\hbar = 6.582\times 10^{-16}eV \cdot s$, and $1 \; eV = 10^{-9}\; GeV$

Comment: The Google calculator says `hbar/(2.141 GeV)` is $3.07432018\times 10^{-25}$ seconds.

Answer (score 1):

[You might want to check that value for $\hbar$ carefully.](https://www.google.com/search?q=h%2F%282*pi%29+in+GeV*s&oq=h%2F%282*pi%29+in+GeV*s)